# Using Mount Propagation bidirectional without Privileged Security context in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, containers, csi-driver

I'm implementing support to a CSIDriver that uses Bidirectional Mount Propagation. This requires that the container be [Privileged](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#:%7E:text=allowed%20only%20in%20privileged%20containers), but in this project, we are not allowed to use privileged containers.

There is any other way to do this? I've tried to use SYS_ADMIN capability, but it did not work.

```yaml
    - name: spiffe-csi-driver
        image: ghcr.io/spiffe/spiffe-csi-driver:0.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: [
          "-workload-api-socket-dir", "/spire-agent-socket",
          "-csi-socket-path", "/spiffe-csi/csi.sock",
        ]
        env:
          - name: MY_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /spire-agent-socket
            name: spire-agent-socket
            readOnly: true
          - mountPath: /spiffe-csi
            name: spiffe-csi-socket-dir
          # The volume containing mount points for containers.
          - mountPath: /var/lib/kubelet/pods
            mountPropagation: Bidirectional
            name: mountpoint-dir
        securityContext:
          privileged: true # need to remove
          # capabilities: # this didn't work 
          #   add:
          #   - SYS_ADMIN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to K8s [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation):

> it is allowed only in privileged containers.